# which is better in performance request.setAttribute or jsp scriptlet code

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I am doing project with struts2.  I have list of ads.
There is an ads table with detail information for the adds.
I want to show list of adds.

So i want to know which is better solution to implement this?

1. In action class i will fetch the objects & store them into list object & set this list object to request
   request.setAttribute(list);

   and on jsp page retrieve & show
2. fetch the object & show it on jsp page using scriptlet <% %>

Please tell which are best practices to do this?

Comment: Why don't you retrieve the data from the database, store it in an attribute in the action and then access it with Struts2 tags (with `<s:iterator>` if it's a list)?

Comment: I am retriving data from database & stoing in list but the question starts from that points whether this code should appear in jsp page or action class

Comment: Thanks to all. Each of you given me helpful information.
i will go with Umesh Awasthi answer i should take advantage of ognl

Comment: You can use ONGL with tags but, take this in mind: ONGL is a powerful tool and you should not take advantage of it. Use tags and only ONGL when it is really needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will suggest not to do any of the above as S2 is providing a more elegant and more flexible approach to set and fetch object in request and response.

You can follow this approach.

In you action class create a list with its setters and getters and fill the object with whatever data you want to fill

```
public class MYActionClass extends ActionSupport{

  private List<Data Type as per your need> myList;
  // getters

  public String execute() throws Exception{

    // you logic
    myList=fill list with the data
  }
}
```

Above code will let S2 to place the `myList` in the `valueStack` and you can use OGNL to fetch data in your JSP.Make sure to have getters and setters so as S2 can fetch and put the data in the list.

in you jsp you have all way to access list using OGNL, i can not suggest you the way how to access the list data as you have not mentioned as how you want to access data in JSP and in what way but using OGNL is quite straight forward like [iterator](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/iterator.html)

i suggest to have look at [OGNL](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/ognl.html) basisc.

Do not use scrip lets as there are more good and flexible way to access data

Comment: I just wanted to point out that you don't need a setter for myList, only a getter, as the value is set in execute.

Answer (score 3):

First is better, because:

- java code on jsp files is evil(html+javascript+jstl tags mb+java code = difficult for maintain)
- jsp is just view(MVC pattern), logic on views is bad idea

Comment: There is nothing wrong having logic in the view as long it concerns on how to display the model data and/or some validations like not empty input components or text length.

Comment: In general I disagree, struts2 has a well established validation system. Then the purpose of the action is to invoke the service layer and prepare data for the view. If you think the view needs something specific, prepare it in the action. There are exceptions I suppose but this is someone who is starting off and exceptions aren't the right thing to focus on, as such I emphasize it is extremely atypical to have anything but trivial logic in the view.

Answer (score 3):

First one. You should avoid to use scriptlet in JSP since that is a very ugly practice and violates the MVC pattern. Instead, you should use JSP tags, specially [JSTL](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135995.html) tags. Also, if you are working with Struts, you have [more tags](http://struts.apache.org/1.2.9/userGuide/struts-html.html) that Struts provides to you.

Take in mind that if there is something that you cannot do with tags, it means that you should not do it.